# Is it bad for performence if store this data in memory instead of database table?

Tags: php, database

I want to install a game on my site. The interaction takes a lot of jobs, mainly about moving the game's options to my site's admin option control pannel. To avoid the interaction job, I'm thinking to make a Class to store the options, and call the calss by Global.

```
Class Game_Vars{
var ...;
... ...;
}
Global $game_options;
if ( !isset( $game_options ) ) $game_options = new Game_vars();
```

By this way, the options won't be stored in database, and the Class.php will be loaded everytime when the game script is running. There are nearly 70 options, is this too heavy for performence?

Comment: This would depend on the server resources and the amount of traffic. Whether storing the data in a database or in a class does not matter as it would be loaded into RAM upon page load either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how `static` the data is, which tells you how easy is must be to change the data. If the data never changes and does not need an interface to change it, then there is nothing wrong with using a class and storing your data in memory. Otherwise, use a database to better manage the data (but fetch the data once from the database using a design pattern such as a Singleton or a single static variable).

You will not run into any memory / hardware performance / efficiency issues when storing 70 data members of a class into memory on any semi-modern server. Especially since (as Pastor Bones points out) that regardless of which option you choose (database or file), all of the options will be loaded into memory at some point.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes file access is faster than mySQL for heavier sites. If your options are read-only, and you will have a huge number of concurrent users (concurrent connections), it might be better to use a file to store your options instead of the mySQL table.

The problem with mySQL is not the amount of data (relatively) but the number of connections.

Comment: in fact, MySQL will cache the data in memory which effectively increases performance because the data must not be read from filesystem each time it is accessed. managing database connections is indeed something that should be done properly, for example using PDO.

Comment: Repetitive request of the same query, even with 1 million user will force mysql to cache, nothing will be faster than a mysql result cached in memory. File access on the disk is usualy much slower than ANYTHING you'd want to accomplish unless you use a memory based disk that is volatile.